# Error running svn in Android studio after xcode upgrade (mac os x el capitan)

Tags: svn, android-studio, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

when updgading XCODE to Version 7.1 (7B91b) Android studio cannot run SVN
I have this message :

```
Error “can't use subversion command line client : svn” when opening android project checked out from svn.
```

When i try to run SVN in the terminal console I have the next message :

```
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `sudo /usr/bin/svn` in terminal console , read the the license agreement(space bar to scroll) and accept it by type the word `agree` when asked.

re-start Android Studio, svn must work now.

It worked for me.